# If $f$ is increasing on an open interval and continuous at endpoints, it's increasing on the closed interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Prove that if $f$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $a$ and $b$, then $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$. The question then clarifies: "In particular, if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f'>0$ on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$.

An idea I had was to consider $\varepsilon > 0$, and to note that $f$ is increasing on $[a+\varepsilon, b-\varepsilon]$. Then, since $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$ and $\lim_{x \to b}f(x)=f(b)$, we can get some contradiction that it's strictly increasing by using the intermedate value theorem for some $c$ s.t. if $a<c<b \Rightarrow f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$. Sorry if this attempt is confusing.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. Suppose $a<u\le b$. How exactly are you proving that $f(a)<f(u)$? Where is the $c$ you mention coming from, and how does it help?

Answer (score 5):

What we need to prove is that if $a < x < b$ then $f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b)$. Let us suppose that $a < y < x$ then we have $f(y) \leq f(x)$. Keeping $x$ fixed and letting $y \to a^{+}$ we get $\lim_{y \to a^{+}}f(y) \leq f(x)$ i.e. $f(a) \leq f(x)$. Similarly we can show that $f(x) \leq f(b)$. Note that the continuity at end points $a, b$ ensures that the desired limits used in above argument exist. Also note that by increasing I am actually referring to "non-decreasing".

If by increasing you mean the "strict" version, then the proof needs to be modified slightly as we need to show $f(a) < f(x) < f(b)$. Let $a < z < y < x$. Keep $x, y$ fixed and then we get $f(z) < f(y) < f(x)$. Letting $z\to a^{+}$ we get $f(a) \leq f(y) < f(x)$ so that $f(a) < f(x)$ and similarly we have $f(x) < f(b)$.

The second part dealing with $f' > 0$ can be easily handled via Mean Value Theorem instead of going through this route.

Comment: why in the strict version, when taking the limit, $f(z) < (fy)$ is converted to $f(a) <= f(y)$ instead of $f(a) < f(y)$, also in both versions, are you using a one sided version of the squeeze theorem or what? I don't get it

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba: well it isn't squeeze theorem but rather a general result about taking limits of inequalities. Taking limits weakens the inequality. A simple example is that $1/x>0$ for all $x>0$ but taking limits as $x\to\infty$ we get $0\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you refer me to some source explaining and proving limits of inequalities? I was reading spivak recently and I didn't find such a thing

Comment: Ok I proved it using epsilon and delta, thanks a lot =)

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba: you may have a look at my blog post: https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-4.html?m=0

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your argument; I'll give you an informal idea on how to prove by contraddiction that $f(b) \geq f(x)$ for any $x \in (a, b)$:

Suppose $f(x_0) > f(b)$ for some $x_0 \in (a, b)$. Intuitively, since $f$ is continuous at $b$, if $x$ is close to $b$ then $f(x)$ is close to $f(b)$. Therefore, if $x$ is close to $b$ and $f(x_0) > f(b)$, then also $f(x_0) > f(x)$, contraddicting the fact that $f$ is increasing on $(a, b)$.

Can you formalize the above argument? Similarly, you can prove $f(a) \leq f(x)$; concluding that $f$ is increasing on $[a, b]$ is easy from here.